# Play sound with OpenAL(Stream)

Tags: c++, openal

I need to play sound which I take from network. Every 10ms, a take 882 bytes of sound(mono, 16 bits, 44100 Hz). And doing this:

```
while (!ExitKey)
    {
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = VoiceSocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        if (len==0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        alGenSources(1, &alSource);
        alGenBuffers(1, &alSampleSet);
        alBufferData(alSource, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
        alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet);
        alSourcePlay(alSource);
    }
```

But my sound isn't play. In buf variable i have sound, because if i send this to file, i have sound in file.

Answer (score 4):

Your code does not show an `alListener`. This seems like a bit too obvious as mistake, but no listener, no sound is heard, and otherwise the posted code should produce some sound, assuming there is non-zero data coming in from the socket.

**EDIT:** On a second look, you have a small typo which has a big consequence. `alBufferData(alSource, ...)` should be `alBufferData(alSampleSet, ...)`. You want to fill the buffer object, not the source. Otherwise, you're playing an empty buffer, which unsurprisingly doesn't produce a sound.

Also do note that your code in general is inefficient and will not work as intended.

You definitively do not want to generate a new source (and buffer) for every packet you receive every 10ms. This will produce *some* sound, but not what you want. Even without network jitter (which you will inevitably have) this won't play nicely without audible gaps.

Generate one source and at least 3 buffers (better a few more, 5 or 6) before entering the loop. The one source lives for as long as you're streaming, and it keeps playing for that time.

Receive at least 2 buffers before entering the loop. Queue these buffers to the source (`alSourceQueueBuffers`) in the order you received them and start playing. Whenever you receive a new packet, read the data into a new buffer (pull it from a free list of allocated buffers) and queue it.

Unqueue buffers and recyle them into your free list as they become free (query first!).

That way, OpenAL always has some data to read while playing back sound, which is crucial for getting a good result. Never let it starve.

Comment: Thanks. if I edit alSource to alSampleSet in alBufferData i have sound. But i don't understand about queue of buffers. What i need to do with buffers? If i queue first buffer and play this in first iteration, second in second etc. I have in speakers repeating clicks.

Comment: Those clicks are what I am talking about ("_some_ sound, but not what you want"). The clicks happen because OpenAL runs out of data while playing -- you must never let that happen. Receive several buffers first _before starting playback_ and queue those to give AL a bit of data ahead. Then (while the source is still playing) as new packets come in also queue these. Never stop playing, never switch sources, never stop feeding. Your playback will start maybe 20-50ms later, but that's fine, nobody will notice. Those repeated clicks, however, everybody notices.

Comment: If I understand what you have explained, I have failed. My code is below.

Answer (score 0):

So if there is valid data in raw buffer then is need to check the OpenAL functions with alGetError to see if some of them failed and find out why they failed. From question description I didn't see that this basic check was done.

Comment: if i paste this after alSourcei(...); i have AL_INVALID_NAME error.

Answer (score 0):

I write this code:

```
void Sound::GoChat()
{
    device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
    //
    ofstream file;
    file.open("TESTSPEAKER", std::ios_base::binary);
    context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(context);
    // alGetError();
    char *alBuffer;
    ALenum alFormatBuffer;
    ALsizei alFreqBuffer;
    long alBufferLen;
    ALboolean alLoop;
    unsigned int alSource;
    unsigned int alSampleSet[3];
    boost::array <char, 882> buf;
    int NumberOfSampleSet = 0;
    alGenSources(1, &alSource);
    alGenBuffers(3, alSampleSet);
    //
    alBufferData(alSampleSet[0], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
    alBufferData(alSampleSet[1], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
    alBufferData(alSampleSet[2], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(alSource, 3, alSampleSet);
    //
    while (!ExitKey)
    {
        alSourceUnqueueBuffers(alSource, 3, alSampleSet);
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t len = VoiceSocket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
        if (len==0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        file.write(buf.data(), 882);

        alBufferData(alSampleSet[0], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
        alBufferData(alSampleSet[1], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);
        alBufferData(alSampleSet[2], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, buf.data(), buf.size(), 44100);

        alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[0]);
        alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[1]);
        alSourcei(alSource, AL_BUFFER, alSampleSet[2]);
            alSourceQueueBuffers(alSource, 3, alSampleSet);
        //
        //alSourcei(alSource, AL_LOOPING, alSampleSet);         
        alSourcePlay(alSource);
        alErr = alGetError();
        //
    }
    VoiceSocket->close();
    file.close();
}
```

but this is dont work too(

Comment: The above call to `alSourceUnqueueBuffers` with `n = 3` works only _after 3 buffers have been processed_ (read the documentation!). This makes using 3 buffers in the first place absurd, because then you have the same problem as if only using 1 buffer. You want to queue _several_ buffers, keep always one or more in the queue, and unqueue _at most 1 at a time (if it's done) when queueing a new one_. This can be done by either polling the status, or simply calling `alSourceUnqueueBuffers` with an argument of **1**. This call either fails (buffer still playing) or succeeds (buffer unqueued).

Comment: Also, you're just overwriting your array of descriptors, it will need to be a little bit more complex. If you don't want to use a queue (probably overkill) you need to maintain at least an index into the array that increments and wraps around, so you write back each unqueued descriptor in an empty place (instead of overwriting stuff).

Comment: Ok. I need queue 3 buffers. And in 3 buffers same data? Why? Or I need  3 different buffers in queue and after iteration unqueue 1 buffer, and  queue new 1 buffer?

Comment: If you can, please give me little example, in that i can understand this thing. I really dont understand this :(.